# PHPUnit Tests Return Blank Terminal Prompt (Sometimes)

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, terminal, phpunit

I'm using MAMP and have configured PHPUnit + Selenium successfully.

I have two unit tests -- one of them works and indicates no errors, the other just returns back to a blank Terminal prompt (no success/failure indication).

**Working:**

*DbTest.php*

```
<?php
class DbTest extends CTestCase
{
    public function testConnection()
    {
        $this->assertNotEquals(NULL, Yii::app()->db);
    }   
}
```

**Not Working:**

*ProjectTest.php*

```
<?php
class ProjectTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public function testCRUD()
    {
        //Create a new project
        $newProject= new Project;
        $newProjectName = 'Test Project 1';
        $newProject->setAttributes(
            array(
                'name' => $newProjectName,
                'description' => 'Test project numero uno',
                'create_time' => '2011-05-20 00:00:00',
                'create_user_id' => 1,
                'update_time' => '2011-05-20 00:00:00',
                'update_user_id' => 1,
                )
            );
            $this->assertTrue($newProject->save(false));

        //Read a project

        $retrievedProject = Project::model()->findByPk($newProject->id);
        $this->assertTrue($retrievedProject instanceof Project);
        $this->assertEquals($newProjectName, $retrievedProject->name);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run phpunit unit/Dbtest.php, I get:

```
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb
```

But, if I run phpunit unit/ProjectTest.php, I get a blank prompt:

```
Trenton-Scotts-MacBook-Air:tests TTS$
```

Using MySQL, DB connection works (I successfully modeled a table using Gii in the Yii framework). Any idea on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unmatched `}` after the `$this->assertEquals($newProjectName, $retrievedProject->name);` line.

Delete the unmatched `}`

Comment: I just caught that too. That was it! Thanks.